# SUMPRODUCT formula on visible rows only and skip 0's in visible rows

Tags: excel-formula, visible, sumproduct, filtered

The formula below works to return the sumproduct (weighted average) on visible rows only. However, I need this formula to also skip visible rows where the value is 0.

This is the formula I am using for sumproduct on visible rows only:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($G$2:$G$101,ROW($G$2:$G$101)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$101)),,1)),$G$2:$G$101,AH2:AH101)/SUBTOTAL(9,$G$2:$G$101)
```

I have another formula that returns the sumproduct and skips rows that have a value of 0 in AH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AH2:AH101,$G$2:$G$101)/SUMPRODUCT(--(AH2:AH101<>0),$G$2:$G$101)
```

But what I need is a combination of these 2 formulas. I need the formula to provide the sumproduct on visible rows only AND skips rows that have a value of 0 in AH.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Bump...anyone able to take a crack at this?